# Getting filenotfound error when trying to open a h5 file

Tags: python, file, h5py

I have a h5 file that contains the "catvnoncat" dataset. when I try to run the following code, I get an error which I will include at the bottom.  I have tried getting the dataset from three different sources to exclude to possibility of a corrupted file.

What I would like to know is what is causing the problem?

```py
# My Code
import h5py
train_dataset = h5py.File('train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
```

```py
# The Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Downloads\Compressed\coursera-deep-learning-specialization-master_2\coursera-deep-learning-specialization-master\C1 - Neural Networks and Deep Learning\Week 2\Logistic Regression as a Neural Network\lr_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    train_dataset = h5py.File('train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
  File "C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 507, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 220, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'train_catvnoncat.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Comment: Well, is the file there? As in the local working directory? Could you open it with the normal ```open``` function?

Comment: @Homer512 my file is definitely there and I have opened it using the HDFView software.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. If you can show that ```open('train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")``` works without throwing an exception when written in the same script, then we can search for more obscure errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking in the current directory which is not where the file is.

Based on the error message, it looks like you are on windows. Is the file 'train_catvnoncat.h5' in your Downloads folder? Find that file on your system and copy the full path. You can then update this:

```py
train_dataset = h5py.File('train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
```

to something that contains the full path. Similar to this:

```py
train_dataset = h5py.File('C:/Users/Moshen/Downloads/train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
```

Pay attention to the slashes and make sure you update the file path to the actual value.

Comment: My python file and HDF5 file are at the same directory, so this can not be the problem.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: To confirm the current working directory, add `print(os.getcwd())` (and `import os` if necessary) to your code. You can add `os.listdir()` to verify contents.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, probably the datasets.h5 were corrupted

Open this link and download the datasets, from the suggested repository

https://morioh.com/p/ce76c6e2f7f6

The train_dataset should be about 2MB and test_dataset 603KB

https://rpaudel42.github.io/datasets/NN.zip

This worked for me !